# PHP: Erratic behaviour of functions?

Tags: php

What on earth is PHP doing here?

This first line works perfectly, but when I try to check whether the return of the `parse_url` is empty or not, my whole execution is stopped and the infamous White screen appears:

**Working:**

```
$subFolderCheck = ( strlen( parse_url('http://www.example.com', PHP_URL_PATH)) >1  ? true : false);
```

**Making my script go bananas:**

```
$subFolderCheck = ( empty( parse_url('http://www.example.com', PHP_URL_PATH))  ? true : false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) it is explained.

you can not call a function inside empty function

> Note:
>
> empty() only checks variables as
>   anything else will result in a parse
>   error. In other words, the following
>   will not work: empty(trim($name)).

You could assign the return value in variable and check that variable with empty

```
$subFolderCheck=(parse_url('http://www.example.com', PHP_URL_PATH))  ? true : false);

if (empty($subFolderCheck))
{
  //do stuff
}
```